# Построение ромба по его ширине и длине

Tags: c++

Я написал основную часть [кода по построению ромба](http://cppstudio.com/post/2629/). На ввод - символ, который будет являться границей, и ширина (еще одновременно и длина). Но я не могу написать условие, по которому выводится ромб. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num, N;
    char material;
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите 1 для печати ромба '*' \nВведите 2 для печати ромба '+' \nВведите 3 для печати ромба '#' \nПожалуйста, введите число 1 - 3: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "\nВводить нужно только положительные нечетные числа,\nиначе ромб не построится.\n\nВведите высоту ромба (она же является шириной): ";
    cin >> num;
    if (N == 1)
    {
        material = '*';
    }
    else if (N == 2)
    {
        material = '+';
    }
    else
    {
        material = '#';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j ++)
        {
            /*Не знаю, как здесь написать условие? Т.е. если нужно,
            вывожу material, если нет, то пробел?*/
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "высоту ромба (она же является шириной)" - чего уж там, называйте его прямо - квадратом

Comment: Нет, он должен быть вот так: http://cppstudio.com/post/2629/

Comment: У меня иногда возникает ощущение, что я говорю на каком-то другом языке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно Вашему коду, вот необходимое условие. Впишите его на месте комментария!

```
if (i + num / 2 == j || i - num / 2 == j || i == num / 2 - j || i == num / 2 + num - j - 1)
{
    cout << material;
}
else
{
    cout << " ";
}
```

Результат:

[image: Снимок экрана]

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте не готовый код давал с указанием, куда его поместить, а описал алгоритм. Тут же на лицо проблема с пониманием того, что должно происходить в цикле.